# BehaviourSubject's distinctUntilChanged() is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I am new to Rxjs
I am trying understand BehaviourSubject
below is my code

```
export interface State {
    items: Items[]
}

const defaultState = {
    items: []
};

const _store = new BehaviorSubject<State>(defaultState);

@Injectable()
export class Store {
    private _store = _store;
    changes = this._store.distinctUntilChanged()
        .do(() => console.log('changes'));

    setState(state: State) {
        this._store.next(state);
    }

    getState() : State {
        return this._store.value;
    }

    purge() {
        this._store.next(defaultState);
    }
}
```

When i run my project then i get this error in my console

```
platform-browser.umd.js:1900 EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise):
EXCEPTION: Error during instantiation of Store! (StoreHelper -> Store).
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: this._store.distinctUntilChanged is not a function
```

Can anyone help me out. Also if I am trying to do is to create a Store for my model objects so if there is any other simpler way feel free to suggest it.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

you have to import entire rxJs library or the specific one for this.

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/distinctUntilChanged';
```

**Update rxjs > 5.5** with Pipeable Operators,

```
import { distinctUntilChanged } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

Pipeable operators helps building and tree shaking.

To learn more on the [benefits of Pipeable operators you may look in here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md).

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Hi, you might help me, I have webstorm and when i'm using Lettable Operators, Webstorm keep them as "unused" imports

Answer (score 4):

You actually have to import all operators (that's `do` and `distinctUntilChanged`) and the `BehaviorSubject` as well.

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/distinctUntilChanged';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
```

See plnkr demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/Wbqv95EiG8BnzC8BpD7E?p=preview

Btw, I'd be careful with statements such as `private _store = _store` because it makes it very hard to read even though it does what you want.

This is generated from https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/.

```
define(["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {
    "use strict";
    var _store = new BehaviorSubject(defaultState);
    var Store = (function () {
        function Store() {
            this._store = _store;
            this.changes = this._store.distinctUntilChanged()
                .do(function () { return console.log('changes'); });
        }
        Store.prototype.setState = function (state) {
            console.log(_store);
            this._store.next(state);
        };
        Store.prototype.getState = function () {
            return this._store.value;
        };
        Store.prototype.purge = function () {
            this._store.next(defaultState);
        };
        return Store;
    }());
    exports.Store = Store;
});
```