# Get unique values from array of objects

Tags: javascript, unique

I have an array of dynamic objects like that:

```
var arr = [
    {state: "FL"},
    {state: "NY"},
    {state: "FL"},
    {gender: "Male"},
    {state: "NY"},
    {gender: "Female"},
    {gender: "Female"},
    {year: "1990"}
]
```

How can I get just the unique objects?

The desired output is an array containing just the unique objects:

```
arr = [
    {state: "FL"},
    {state: "NY"},
    {gender: "Male"},
    {gender: "Female"},
    {year: "1990"}
]
```

I'm trying something like that using reduce, but on this way I need know the object key:

```
arr = arr.reduce((acc, curr) => 
    acc.find(e => e['state'] === curr['state']) ? acc : [...acc, curr], [])
```

It's not a duplicate because the other questions does not use "dynamic object" to get unique

Comment: What the desired output?

Comment: `.find(e => JSON.stringify(e) === JSON.stringify(curr))` would be a quick and dirty way of doing it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to use javascript reduce on an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54901129/how-to-use-javascript-reduce-on-an-array-of-objects)

Comment: Does your objects always only have one key with a string value? If no, could you tell me more about them, so I can try to give a specific solution instead of using JSON.stringify that could be very slow for a big array.

Comment: Objects can have more than one key, but the values is always string. var arr = [
    {state: "FL", year: "1980", class: "A"},
    {state: "NY"},
    {state: "FL"},
    {gender: "Male"},
    {state: "NY"},
    {gender: "Female"},
    {gender: "Female"},
    {year: "1990"}
]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could stringify all objects, get the unique JSON and then convert the strings back to objects.

```js
var array = [{ state: "FL" }, { state: "NY" }, { state: "FL" }, { gender: "Male" }, { state: "NY" }, { gender: "Female" }, { gender: "Female" }, { year: "1990" }],
    unique = Array.from(
        new Set(array.map(JSON.stringify)),
        JSON.parse
    );
    
console.log(unique);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

If you have more than one key in the object and because if you have objects where the keys are in different order, I suggest you to get the entries first, sort this array, stringify it for a set, and then get the new objects back.

```js
var array = [{ foo: 42, state: "FL" }, { state: "FL", foo: 42 }, { state: "FL" }, { state: "NY" }, { state: "FL" }, { gender: "Male" }, { state: "NY" }, { gender: "Female" }, { gender: "Female" }, { year: "1990" }],
    unique = Array.from(
        new Set(array.map(o => JSON.stringify(Object.entries(o).sort(([a], [b]) => a.localeCompare(b))))),
        s => Object.assign({}, ...JSON.parse(s).map(([k, v]) => ({ [k]: v })))
    );
    
console.log(unique);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can `reduce` to an object where each value in your objects is a key in this one (as objects can't double up on keys - thus allowing you to get unique values), and then use that with `Object.values` to get the values within your reduced object like so:

```js
const arr = [{state: "FL"},{state: "NY"},{state: "FL"},{gender: "Male"},{state: "NY"},{gender: "Female"},{gender: "Female"},{year: "1990"}]
const res = Object.values(arr.reduce((acc, obj) => {
  const [[key, val]] = Object.entries(obj);
  return (acc[val] = {[key]: val}, acc);
}, {}));

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 2):

quick way which comes to my mind given the simplicity of given objects

1. convert all objects to string using `JSON.stringify`
2. get all unique values by converting that array of string to `set`
3. convert strings again to objects

```js
var arr = [{state: "FL"},{state: "NY"},{state: "FL"},{gender: "Male"},{state: "NY"},{gender: "Female"},   {gender: "Female"},{year: "1990"}
]

const stringArr = arr.map(str => JSON.stringify(str));
const uniqueStrs = [ ...new Set(stringArr)] // removes duplicates
const result = uniqueStrs.map(str => JSON.parse(str));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

I know, I know, me too... but my answer's a bit more succinct.

```
[...new Set(arr.map(JSON.stringify))].map(JSON.parse);
```

This has the usual caveats with using `JSON.stringify`, namely that according to spec, you can't rely on the order of keys to be consistent.  If you only have a single key, this will never be a problem.  It also likely won't be a problem if every object is constructed by adding keys in the same order, as most implementations will preserve key-added order.

Answer (score 1):

This perform will much better than anything using JSON.parse and stringify.

```js
var arr = [
    {state: "FL"},
    {state: "NY"},
    {state: "FL"},
    {gender: "Male"},
    {state: "NY"},
    {gender: "Female"},
    {gender: "Female"},
    {year: "1990"}
];

const unique = arr => arr.filter((item, index) => !arr.some((i, idx) => idx > index && Object.getOwnPropertyNames(item).every(property => i[property] === item[property])));

console.log(unique(arr));
```

or with reduce instead of filter like you were trying

```js
var arr = [
    {state: "FL"},
    {state: "NY"},
    {state: "FL"},
    {gender: "Male"},
    {state: "NY"},
    {gender: "Female"},
    {gender: "Female"},
    {year: "1990"}
];

const unique = arr => arr.reduce((results, item) => {
  if (!results.some(i => Object.getOwnPropertyNames(item).every(property => i[property] === item[property]))) {
    results.push(item);
  }
  return results;
}, []);

console.log(unique(arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```js
const arr = [
  { state: 'FL' },
  { state: 'NY' },
  { state: 'FL' },
  { gender: 'Male' },
  { state: 'NY' },
  { gender: 'Female' },
  { gender: 'Female' },
  { year: '1990' },
];

arr.reduce((array, obj) => {
  for (const target of array) {
    if (JSON.stringify(target) === JSON.stringify(obj)) {
      return array;
    }
    return [...array, obj];
  }
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

A lot of ways to do this: here are two:

1. `reduce`
2. `for loop`

```js
var arr = [
    {state: "FL"},
    {state: "NY"},
    {state: "FL"},
    {gender: "Male"},
    {state: "NY"},
    {gender: "Female"},
    {gender: "Female"},
    {year: "1990"}
]

//two solutions
//1. reduce and some
let arr1 = arr.reduce( (acc, currentValue) => {
    const key = Object.keys(currentValue)[0]; //we only have one property!
    const inArr = acc.some((element) => {return element[key] == currentValue[key]});
    if (!inArr)
    {
      acc.push(currentValue);
    }
    return acc;

  },[]);

console.log(arr1);

//2. for loop
//you can still do a for loop (Quick):
const shadow = [];
const iMax= arr.length;
for (let i = 0; i < iMax; i++)
{
   const key = Object.keys(arr[i])[0]; //we only have one property!
  //check if value is not in shadow array
  if (shadow.indexOf(arr[i][key]) == -1)
  {
    arr.push(arr[i]);
    shadow.push(arr[i][key]);
  }
}
//splice off the original values
arr.splice(0, iMax);
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `filter` method :

```js
var arr = [ 
  {state: "FL"}, {state: "NY"}, {state: "FL"}, {gender: "Male"},
  {state: "NY"}, {gender: "Female"}, {gender: "Female"}, {year: "1990"}
]

var len = arr.length ;
var result = [] ;

var result = arr.filter( (cur, inx) => {
  var same = 0 ;
  var curKey = Object.keys(cur)[0] ;
  for ( var i = inx + 1; i < len; i++ ) 
    if ( cur[curKey] === arr[i][curKey] ) { same++; break; }
  return !same;
})

console.log( result ) ;
```