# Reduce an array of objects an keep only one object of each id depending on another data

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, reduce

I'm pretty new to coding and I'm working on a problem. I can't fully understand how reduce function work.
So basically I have an array of objects which are topics, each topic contains an article. When I click on a button it will append a topic.
I need to append the articles only when I click otherwise it will show all topics without articles.

```
let buttonValue = 1;

const topics = [{
    id: 1,
    article: {"date" : "01-01-2022", "title" : "title1", "summary" : "summary1"}
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    article: {"date" : "01-01-2022", "title" : "title2", "summary" : "summary2"}
  },
  
  {
    id: 3,
    article: {"date" : "01-01-2022", "title" : "title3", "summary" : "summary3"}
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    article: {"date" : "01-01-2022", "title" : "title4", "summary" : "summary4"}
  },{
    id: 1,
    article: {"date" : "01-02-2022", "title" : "title5", "summary" : "summary5"}
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    article: {"date" : "01-02-2022", "title" : "title6", "summary" : "summary6"}
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    article: {"date" : "01-02-2022", "title" : "title7", "summary" : "summary7"}
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    article: {"date" : "01-02-2022", "title" : "title5", "summary" : "summary5"}
  },
];
```

Result should be:

```
const topics = [
  {
    id: 1,
    article: [{"date" : "01-01-2022", "title" : "title1", "summary" : "summary1"}, {"date" : "01-02-2022", "title" : "title5", "summary" : "summary5"}, {"date" : "01-02-2022", "title" : "title5", "summary" : "summary5"}]
 },
  {
    id: 4,
    article: {"date" : "01-01-2022", "title" : "title4", "summary" : "summary4"}
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    article: {"date" : "01-02-2022", "title" : "title6", "summary" : "summary6"}
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    article: {"date" : "01-02-2022", "title" : "title7", "summary" : "summary7"}
  },

];
```

Here is my code:

```
const articleArray = topics.reduce((acc,cur) => {
  const found = acc.find(topic => topic.id == cur.id && topic.id === buttonValue);
  return found ? found.article.push(cur.article) : acc.push({...cur, article:[cur.article]}), acc;
}, []);

const uniqueTopic = Array.from(new Set(articleArray.map(topic => topic.id)))
 .map(id => {
   return articleArray.find(element => element.id === id)
 })
```

I have some difficulties to understand how the reduce work because when I console log found it returned undefined. Can someone explain it?
Is there another way to directly accumulate and reduce the array without uniqueTopic function?
I tried:

```
const reducedArr = topics.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  acc[cur.id] && (cur.id === buttonValue)
    ? (acc[cur.id].push({...cur, article:[cur.article]}))
    : (acc[cur.id] = cur);
  return acc;
}, {});
```

It returned undefined.

Comment: check this article out it might be of help https://stackoverflow.com/a/54901360/11120306

Comment: Why is id: 2, 3 , and 4 only one object in result?

Comment: *" I need to append the articles only when I click otherwise it will show all topics without articles."* It looks like each topic has articles. How are you actually handling the click event? Wouldn't it be easier to just reduce all articles into the topic they belong to then as the button is clicked only the topic that matches the button value is used?

Answer (score 0):

One issue I noticed was no empty array had been initialized to push new items.

Try this to build the reduced array using [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), and [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```js
const topics = [ { id: 1, article: { date: "01-01-2022", title: "title1", summary: "summary1" }, }, { id: 2, article: { date: "01-01-2022", title: "title2", summary: "summary2" }, }, { id: 3, article: { date: "01-01-2022", title: "title3", summary: "summary3" }, }, { id: 4, article: { date: "01-01-2022", title: "title4", summary: "summary4" }, }, { id: 1, article: { date: "01-02-2022", title: "title5", summary: "summary5" }, }, { id: 2, article: { date: "01-02-2022", title: "title6", summary: "summary6" }, }, { id: 3, article: { date: "01-02-2022", title: "title7", summary: "summary7" }, }, { id: 1, article: { date: "01-02-2022", title: "title5", summary: "summary5" }, }, ];

const reducedArr = Object.entries(
  topics.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    if (!acc[cur.id]) {
      acc[cur.id] = [];
    }
    acc[cur.id].push(cur.article);
    return acc;
  }, {})
).map(([id, articles]) => ({ id, articles }));

console.log(reducedArr);
```

Comment: @elo-ly, check this out !!

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Thank you for your help :) !

Answer (score 0):

**can you check this once please**

```js
const topics = [{
    id: 1,
    article: {"date" : "01-01-2022", "title" : "title1", "summary" : "summary1"}
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    article: {"date" : "01-01-2022", "title" : "title2", "summary" : "summary2"}
  },
  
  {
    id: 3,
    article: {"date" : "01-01-2022", "title" : "title3", "summary" : "summary3"}
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    article: {"date" : "01-01-2022", "title" : "title4", "summary" : "summary4"}
  },{
    id: 1,
    article: {"date" : "01-02-2022", "title" : "title5", "summary" : "summary5"}
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    article: {"date" : "01-02-2022", "title" : "title6", "summary" : "summary6"}
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    article: {"date" : "01-02-2022", "title" : "title7", "summary" : "summary7"}
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    article: {"date" : "01-02-2022", "title" : "title5", "summary" : "summary5"}
  },
];
const fun = (ar)=>{
 const output = ar.reduce((prev, curr) => {
  const tmp = prev.find(e => e.id===curr.id);
    if (tmp) {
      tmp.article.push(curr.article)
    } else {
      prev.push({
       id : curr.id,
       article : [curr.article]
      });
    }
    return prev;
  }, []);
  return output
}
console.log(fun(topics))
```